# Rails 5 Unpermitted parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I'm trying do to a simple thing, but i just can't get through!

Simple Notebook app:  Contact, Phone and PhoneType.

Models:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :phones, inverse_of: :contact

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, allow_destroy: true
end

class NumberType < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :phones, inverse_of: :number_types
end

class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :number_type
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

Controller :

```
def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name,
    phone_attributes:[:number, :number_type_id, :contact_id, :_destroy])
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_with(model: contact, local: true) do |form| %>
.
.
.      
      <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :name %>
        <%= form.text_field :name, id: :contact_name %>
      </div>

      <%=form.fields_for :phone do |phone_field| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= phone_field.label :number %>
          <%= phone_field.text_field :number %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= phone_field.label :number_type %>
          <%= collection_select(:phone, :number_type_id, @number_types_for_select, :id, :description) %>

        </div>
      <%end%>
```

The thing is that i can save a new contact,  but it does not save the phone number...  the log says "Unpermitted parameter:"
It saves the contact name... but not the rest...

ALSO i already have a few PhoneType created for the test.

Here is the log:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-21 17:03:48 -0300
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"n4LQ6EjssSBp6yCTOni1B9qKUAygzUJMMTN+12Fth6AO2dblXmySdOdjab/ABg3PI19oF9nsyGIVjYa3YyAVPw==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Mendel", "phone"=>{"number"=>"1234567890"}}, "phone"=>{"number_type_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Contact"}
Unpermitted parameter: :phone
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "contacts" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Mendel"], ["created_at", "2017-07-21 20:03:48.952923"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-21 20:03:48.952923"]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
```

SO! I don't know what to change here. I've been reading answers here but i just can't get it right.  I'm pretty knew to this and self-thought on coding.

Help will be very appreciated! :)

Thank you

<--!  PART 2   --->

So, here's the problem.:

When I create a new contact i get:

Phones number_type must exist.

the view goes as:

```
<div class = "nested-fields"> 
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :number %>
        <%= f.text_field :number %>

        <%= f.label :number_type %>
        <%= collection_select(:phone, :number_type_id, NumberType.all, :id, :description) %>
        <%= link_to_remove_association('[delete]',f)%>
    </div>
</div>
```

as a partial called at:

```
<%=form.fields_for :phones do |phone_field| %>
      <%= render partial: "phone_fields", locals: {f: phone_field} %> 
<%end%>    
<%=link_to_add_association('[+ phone]', form, :phones)%>
```

is it a problem with the permission at the Params or with the way i set tup the collection select?

this is what i get at the server:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-22 13:13:24 -0300
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PJxUoaoaAQh5Q7sXKgkUrnfppNQjRTLhdkyaIJdifDKtx1KsvJoiXPfL8jvQd6xmjjycz1pkuM9S8mJAlS/urQ==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Mendel", "phones_attributes"=>{"1500740000317"=>{"number"=>"123456", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "phone"=>{"number_type_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Contact"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Thank you again!

Comment: You need to use `form.fields_for :phones` (plural phones)

Answer (score 1):

Pay careful attention to pluralization in rails. If your association is `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` you need to consistently use the plural form.

```
def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name,
    phones_attributes:[:number, :number_type_id, :contact_id, :_destroy])
end
```

---

```
<%= form_with(model: contact, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :contact_name %>
  </div>

  <%= form.fields_for :phones do |phone_field| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= phone_field.label :number %>
      <%= phone_field.text_field :number %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= phone_field.label :number_type_id %>
      <%= collection_select(:phone, :number_type_id, @number_types_for_select, :id, :description) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: OH MY GOD!  I looked at these things a thousand times... plural there, singular here.... changed and changed.....can't believe that's what i missed!!  Thank you for pointing out!!  :))   thes things are tricky for begginers, i guess!

Comment: Ok! so, that fixed, I bumped into another problem:  when I create a contact, it says that a phone_type must exist. The thing is that os should exist. i set it up at the permitted attributes and i think i did the collection select right, but i gesss not. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i don't know WHY, but i got it to work.

the problem was at the collection_select code.

It was :

```
<%= collection_select(:phone, :number_type_id, NumberType.all, :id, :description) %>
```

It worked as:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:number_type_id, NumberType.all, :id, :description) %>
```

If know why, i'd love to understand!

Thank you!